Как сделать проверку колонок из разных таблиц?
Я новичок в mySQL, и у меня стоит задача, мне нужно что бы проводилась проверка колонки user_login с таблицы bloodcraft.wp_users, и колонки username с таблицы authme.authme2, и если эти колонки не равны (тоесть имеют разные значения) то выполнять следующий код:
INSERT INTO bloodcraft.wp_users (`user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `display_name`, `user_url`) SELECT `username`, `password`, `realname`, `realname`, 'https://тут мой сайт/' FROM authme.authme2;

На данном этапе у меня получился такой запрос:
SELECT `user_login`, `username`, IF(`user_login` != `username`, "YES", "NO") FROM authme.authme2, bloodcraft.wp_users;

Но куда мне вставить мой код с Insert?
Вот результат работы Select, нужно что бы вместо YES выводился код (INSERT...)

Если поставить вместо YES то выдаст ошибку:
#1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MariaDB на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'INTO bloodcraft.wp_users (user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, `displa...' на строке 1
Как мне сделать, что бы при срабатывании условия срабатывал код?

как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?

Ваш второй запрос на выходе даст картезианское множество(все ко всем). В нем нет условий сцепки таблиц. Про сверку "колонок". Поля принадлежат записи и сравнивать можно равенство полей по записям. Уточните, что именно вы хотите сравнивать в полях двух таблиц? Что в одной таблице есть запись с каким то значением, а во второй нет?

Я слегка поменял вопрос, мне нужно сравнивать значение, и если user_login не идентично username, то производить код (INSERT...)

Ещё раз. Вы хотите все со всеми сравнивать? У вас будет максимум одна запись совпадать, а остальные все не совпадут. И так для каждой записи первой таблицы. Вы реально хотите все эти записи куда-то вставить? Грубо говоря, если 30 записей в одной таблице и 30 в другой, то вы вставите почти 900 записей.

В вопросе и тегах у вас MySQL, а ошибку получили от MariaDB. Така какая СУБД используется? По поводу вашего селекта я написал - он чушь возвращает. И в сам селект не вставить insert.

CrazyElf, кратко говоря мне нужно сделать так, что бы в таблицу bloodcraft.wp_users вставлялись данные из authme.authme2 периодически( например каждые 10 минут) и что бы данные не повторялись

Объявите bloodcraft.wp_users.user_login уникальным и вставляйте запросом INSERT IGNORE. Делов-то...

Как я понимаю, в MySQL нет оператора MERGE как в T-SQL, который очень пригодился бы)
Думаю, здесь может помочь инструкция ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, синтаксис будет примерно такой
INSERT INTO bloodcraft.wp_users
(user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, display_name, user_url)
SELECT username, password, realname, realname, 'https://тут мой сайт/' FROM authme.authme2;
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
'user_login' = VALUES('username');

Благодарю, я сделал колонку user_login уникальной, и чуть поменял код:
INSERT INTO bloodcraft.wp_users (user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, display_name, user_url)
SELECT username, password, realname, realname, мой сайт'
FROM authme.authme2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
user_pass = VALUES(user_pass),
user_nicename = VALUES(user_nicename),
display_name = VALUES(display_name),
user_url = VALUES(user_url);
Так или иначе, ваш ответ помог мне решить мою задачу! Очень благодарен!

Отлично) рада была помочь)
